# How to prevent from force restarting when saving file without modifications in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have index.js. I run it with Nodemon on WebStorm in Integrated terminal. When I press command + s shortcut if the file not modified, the Nodemon does not restart. If the file modified, it will restart. So, when I use VS Code and run index.js with nodemon, When I press command + s without file modifying, nodemon restarts. How can I prevent force saving if file not modified on Vscode.

I want WebStorm like feature for smart saving file.

Comment: It would be interesting if there is a solution to this but I don’t think it’s a deal breaker. If you’re that picky don't save the file when there are no changes.

Comment: It looks like Webstorm is not saving the file if it has no modifications. So the workaround is you can do what Webstorm does and manually (instead of automatically) don't save if there are no modifications.